# How to log in to a 2FA site, mobile BankID, using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium

Is is possible to use Selenium to log in to a site that uses a 2 factor autentication method (e.g bankID for a bank)?

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\geckodriver.exe")
# driver.implicitly_wait(2)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("theBankID-page")

try:
    personNumber = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "personNumber")))

    personNumber.send_keys("personNumber")
    personNumber.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

except TimeoutException:
    print("Failed to load BankID-page")
```

The above code makes you manually log in to the site using e.g. your phone as the second factor where you input the password.

But if I go to a new site, and the site is requesting a new log in with BankID when I go to a new page on the site, is it possible to store the log in session the first time? So it is persistent even when I go to a new page on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check their official documentation: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/worst_practices/two_factor_authentication/

It advises you to either disable it or if you can log in using another method that should work.

Comment: It only states: "Automating this seamlessly and consistently is a big challenge in Selenium." It does not answer how it is possible. Just says disable 2FA in test environments but that can't be done if you don't have ownership to the site in question? It does neither say anything if it is possible to scrape after you have manually logged in?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is the `BankID` 2-factor auth is.

If you are using `1password` you could use [cli tool](https://1password.com/downloads/command-line/) to obtain code.
https://1password.community/discussion/102228/how-do-i-retrieve-an-otp-token-value-via-1password-cli

I believed other password manager also provide similar api to do.

you could also use https://github.com/pyauth/pyotp to get the otp given you have the shared secret.

You may be able to persist logged-in session, but that totally depend on the implementation of the site.

for example if the site use cookie. Then, you just get and set the cookies from the logged in to the new session.

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/support_packages/working_with_cookies/

Comment: thats correct. if there is no option to disable 2FA for test environments or for a service user then using OnePassword CLI is an alternative. I have used it in a Bitbucket pipeline to successfully get 2FA codes from microsoft
`op item get "ITEM_ID/one-time-pass-automation"`